# Unsupported operand type array + null in Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, laravel-9

This issue is related to this https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2016

Recently after upgrading our Laravel and PHP to 9 and 8.1 respectively, some guzzle calls are being failed with the error 'Unsupported operand types: array+null. As mentioned in the GitHub ticket, this is not something happening often. Sometimes it fails with this error and as we resend the job it works.

Anyone facing similar issues or have a solution for this ?

[image]

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Either $options or $defaults is not an array (anymore).

Comment: As this is a fairly familiar way to merge a user submitted set of options with a Defaults set of options, I would make sure that the array you are passing in is ALWAYS an array

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your comments. As I mentioned this is not an ideal scenario that happens every time. These jobs when re-run works perfectly. Some times at the first place it just throws this error.

Comment: So if it works second time, it sounds like something is taking time to get put in place and your first attempt was run before this other thing happened

Answer (score 0):

We can figure out what's happening with a small test. Look at this example:

```
public function test(int $someVar) : array|null { ... }
```

If you create this new method with two possibilities of return types (array or null) on a PHP version less than 8, you will receive exactly the same error:

> "Unsupported operand types: array+null"

So, you want to check your Guzzle version and if this version is compatible with PHP 8.0.

Hope it helps.

.